# How to get offsetWidth without waiting after setting fontVariationSettings? It is changing after few ms?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to get offsetWidth without waiting after setting fontVariationSettings via javascript? Then it changes after a few ms and I can't use wait.

I see MutationObserver is also lagging!

```
        span.style.fontFamily = 'Gingham, sans-serif'; 
        span.textContent = str;
        container.appendChild(span);

        // seting...
        span.style.fontVariationSettings = `'wdth' 140`;

        // geting...
        console.log("now: ", span.offsetWidth) // == now:  81
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("after 1000ms: ", span.offsetWidth) // == after 1000ms:  74
        },1000)
```

Comment: _"I see MutationObserver is also lagging"_ - probably due to the fact that it simply takes the browser a bit of time to apply the modified font settings - if it is even doing that all by itself, and not passing part of the rendering off to the OS or something. If the MO already "lags", then I kinda doubt that there will be anything else, and event or something, that could get you the info any faster.

Comment: Could it be that I installed the font with @font-face .

Comment: Doubt it. That is not really "installing", as you would do with font on the OS level - but the browser will in all likelihood already have downloaded the full font at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You should wait your font to be downloaded and applied to get the updated metrics.

I suggest to preload font especially if you code works not on a page load. For example embed your font with a data url.

On my project I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontfaceobserver to watch when a font is loaded and get a proper `offsetWidth`